Line segment dividing problem
There's a math problem that I'm not sure the name of. It goes like this:
You have a line segment one inch long. You must draw two dots so that each one is in a different half. Easy, right? Nope, then add another dot, making three dots so that each one is in a different third. Then, four dots so that each one is in a different fourth, etc... without erasing previous dots. The maximum is eighteen dots or something.
There's a math problem like this, what it's called?

I think Kakeya needle. At least, it sounds similar to me.

@SigmaAlgebra  You mean this?

@lulu Yes, it seems a variant of that to me.

I don't think the link is what I'm looking for. What if you try the instructions above? How many points can you put?
Five or six should be impressive.
Better wording: You have a line segment one inch long. You must draw two dots ON THE LINE so that each one is in a different half, then three, etc.

@ddodd69 Your question was the name of the problem.

I saw this from some puzzle/brain games book from the library. I also remember seeing a youtube video on this, and it wasn't using a triangle or rotating one line or anything like the Kakeya needle.

I don't understand why there should be a maximum of $18$ points. Can't you just go through all the segments at each step, pick a new point only if there isn't already one from the previous step, and otherwise take that again? Take them all irrational so you're sure you'll never pick an intersection of two segments.

@SassatelliGiulio If there are $17$ points that are in different seventeenths of the line segment, and they pass all the previous steps (points $1, \ldots, i$ are in different $i$ths of the line segment, in the order of addition), maybe two of the $17$ points fall into the same eighteenths of the line segment and therefore fail the next step. Is this avoidable for some sequence of $17$ points?

@peterwhy Ah, that's what I was missing. Thanks.

It is only possible to place 17 points in the required manner. Proofs can be found in Berlekamp, E. R. and Graham, R. L. "Irregularities in the Distributions of Finite Sequences." J. Number Th. 2, 152-161, 1970 and Warmus, M. "A Supplementary Note on the Irregularities of Distributions." J. Number Th. 8, 260-263, 1976.
See also Are there any non-casework proofs of the $18$-point problem? and also Puzzle reference request: planting trees in a semicircle orchard
